# Why is my screenshot so dark?

Tags: screenshot

I'm taking screenshots with the <kbd>Print Scr</kbd> button, then copy to clipboard, and paste the result into KoulorPaint. The screenshots are taken from Firefox.

However, everything that is white on the original page, turns light grey in the screenshot.

I made a quick screenshot of this post to illustrate my problem, you'll see that the screenshot is darker than the AskUbuntu page..

I've tested, and this is not a problem of Kolourpaint or Firefox, as it happens also when I screenshot other programs or paste my screenshot into other graphic editors, like the example bellow which was a direct upload from the clipboard to Imgur

[image]

How do I get the original brightness through Ubuntus screenshot function?

Comment: does this only happen with KoulorPaint?

Comment: Does this happen only in Firefox? Edit the post and post another screenshot of the blank `gedit` text-editors window

Comment: Can you edit your question and answer the queries please?

Comment: Updated. I checked gedit and this also turns grey

Comment: @DanielS upload an screenshot of gedit

Comment: Strange enough, today neither gedit or firefox screenshots turn dark.  Which solves my problem, but gives little clue about the origin of the error!

Comment: @DanielS are you using any Firefox addons?

Comment: Does it only happen when you paste in image-editor instead of using `PrntScr` button?

Comment: The reason this appears to happen is because of the "shutter" visual effect. The screen goes black momentarily and, as the brightness comes back up, the screenshot is taken before the screen has returned to full brightness, so it appears darkened. I don't mind the shutter sound-effect, but the visual effect is stupid since it actually messes up the screenshot.