# Why is my screenshot too dark?

Tags: screenshot, gnome-screenshot, xnview

I have the same problem as in this post [Why is my screenshot so dark?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821970/why-is-my-screenshot-so-dark) This post however is closed.

I have the problem with both gnome screenshot and XNview. It does not matter what program I'm taking a screenshot from (as suggested/asked in the related post). So it does not matter if i take a screenshot from Firefox or in this case the document viewer.

Also the problem is aggravating. Today I took three screenshots right after each other. The first one is ok, the second is too dark and the third is even darker!

I have an image that shows this progresively darker screenshots but I can't upload it.

I am using 16.04 64 bits and I am using a dual screen set up.

(Edit Additional Info)

I noticed my whole screen gets darker at each screenshot

So presumably what happens is this:

- when I select screenshot from keyboard something darkens the screen
  a bit (both screens in my case)
- The actual screenshot is taken.
- This is actually a bit dark
- Take next screenshot
- Screen goes even a bit more dark
- Next screenshot is more dark

With the first screenshot the problem is hardly noticable. That is why I said the first one is ok. On close observation it is not.

To check if you have the same problem: make 20 or so screenshots and your screen will be approx at a brightness of 50%

More info:

Pull down menus are not affected. E.g. the small search box in firefox or a pull down selection field in Libre Office show as white once selected while the rest of the screen stays at reduced brightness level.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem on a 16.04.3 64 bit system. What I found is that it's a side effect of taking several screenshots and **not closing** the screenshot dialog.  Whenever I close the screenshot dialog (e.g., after saving or copying and pasting in a nother application) I can take several screenshots (of screenshots) and do not experience the increasing dark shadow.  Closing several screenshot dialogs considerably increases overall desktop brightness...

Comment: @tipavi Oh my god... you're right! With every screenshot dialog I closed, my entire screen got brighter.... wow.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know why my screenshot was so dark. It turns out you're right, closing them all makes my screen super bright and high contrast like how I like now.